# General Runtime Error being displayed instead of stack trace sharepoint 2010

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint

I am trying to add a GridView to the aspx page ,but when I add it I get the error [image: RunTimeError]

I have enabled debugging on the web.config file , but still I get this below error. Since a day I have been trying to add the gridview to the page, it does'nt let me do it. However, I am able to add the same gridview to another aspx page.

Not sure of whats going wrong. Can someone please let me know of how can I get the stack trace which will help me let me know the probl.

Answer (score 0):

Janet, you're going to need to disable custom errors as indicated in the error page you're seeing.  Add **<customErrors mode="Off" />** in the web.config for your site to see the full details of the error.

Comment: I already have customErrors mode="Off" in web.config.It still does not show the details of the error.

Comment: Okay, that's odd. My guess now is that maybe there's another web.config file higher up in the hierarchy of config files which is taking affect instead of the one you're modifying.

How about deleting the web.config file where you've made the "customErrors" change to see if you get a different error screen.

Answer (score 0):

What this means is that when you are *NOT* on the local machine, you will be viewing this type of error whenever a runtime error occurs. When you are viewing this in local machine's browser, you can get the real error page. But, If you want to see this on the browser not on local machine, you WILL have to change web.config

> customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"

to

> customErrors mode="Off"

(Note that mode is case sensitive here, i.e "off" is not same as "Off").